# Is it possible to install ZSNES Emulator from default software sources?

Tags: 11.04, software-sources

I can find it listed when I search for "zsnes" in the Ubuntu Software Center but it doesn't have the "Install" button. If I click the "More information" button I'll get a "package not found" message.

Synaptic can't find this package either.

(from user @REJ) I have Natty 64bit. When I run `sudo apt-get install zsnes` it gives the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done Package zsnes is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'zsnes' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 5):

zsnes exists in the Universe repository for 32bit Natty only.

If you look [here on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+package/zsnes) for the zsnes package, you'll note there is no 64bit package available - just the 32bit (i386) package.

To get this to work under 64bit requires a bit of terminal work...

Download the 32bit package [from here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/i386/zsnes/1.510-2.2ubuntu4) into your Downloads folder.

Install all the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libao4 libc6 libgcc1 libgl1-mesa-glx libpng12-0 libsdl1.2debian libstdc++6 zlib1g
```

Then do the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads
dpkg -x zsnes_1.510-2.2ubuntu4_i386.deb zsnes_dir
cd zsnes_dir/usr/bin
```

You can now run the application by running

```
./zsnes -ad sdl
```

[source](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1H_hkPoUXRN8CODj7fOPTgsjOFysib9FNZors83Cqq5g)

Answer (score 3):

simply run this command first

```
apt-get build-dep zsnes
```

It'll download and install all the 32bit dependencies to get **zsnes** to run. Next you just install **zsnes** as usual using this command

```
apt-get install zsnes
```

finally, after you have successfully installed **zsnes** we just want to get rid of the  dependencies we needed to install/build it by simply running this command

```
aptitude markauto $(apt-cache showsrc zsnes | grep Build-Depends | perl -p -e 's/(?:[\[(].+?[\])]|Build-Depends:|,|\|)//g')
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd share a different strategy that I ran across in the search for installing ZSNES on amd64.

If you don't mind using a different emulator (a better one in my opinion), there is a port of SNES9x available.

First, add these sources to your `sources.list` file in `etc/apt`.

to edit the file as root, open your terminal and type:

```
cd etc/apt
sudo gedit sources.list
```

Once that is opened, add these two lines into the textfile, and save:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bearoso/ppa/ubuntu raring main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/bearoso/ppa/ubuntu raring main
```

ALSO, REPLACE "raring" WITH WHATEVER VERSION OF UBUNTU YOU ARE RUNNING CURRENTLY.

Then, in your terminal, type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Once that is done, install the program using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install snes9x-gtk
```

Once installed, just search for the app in your dashboard, and run it!

Config is simple, and it's a great emu in my opinion, it's been around for years, and this port works great so far.

-Chris

Comment: The recommended way to add a PPA is to either add `ppa:bearoso/ppa` as the deb line entry in the Software and Updates tool or to run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bearoso/ppa` from the Terminal. More detailed instructions can be found from http://askubuntu.com/q/4983/8973

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my desktop, but not for my old laptop.

Have tried a lot of thing to get a working snes emulator. When i was giving it up, i downloaded zsnes for windows and accidentially ran it, and it worked!! I did install PLAYONLINUX from software center some time before that, basically it runs great with WINE. Just make a folder on your desktop (or where you like) and put the downloaded zsnes file there and run it :) If you have problems with gamepad, install JSTEST-GTK and calibrate!!

Hope this help some people..